# Return Count in Procedure - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this procedure into a package, and I need to return the count of a table, but I don't know how do this. I have this and it doesn't work.

```
PROCEDURE OBTENER_TOTALCAMPAÑA(TOTAL OUT NUMBER)
IS
row_count number;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_CARTERA INTO row_count  FROM CLIENTE
RETURNING row_count INTO TOTAL;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You don't need to say returning in this case. Returning is typically used in inserts that you need to get the id from after the row is inserted. In your case, just fill the output param with the select ... INTO from ....

```
PROCEDURE OBTENER_TOTALCAMPAÑA(TOTAL OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_CARTERA INTO TOTAL FROM CLIENTE;

END;
```

Buena suerte

Answer (score 0):

try this. it works for me. create oracle package

```
create or replace PACKAGE LEVEL_CRUD AS 
PROCEDURE INSERT_LEVEL_DATA (
P_LEVEL_ID      IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
P_LEVEL_NAME    IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_NAME%TYPE,
P_CREATED_BY    IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
P_CREATE_DATE   IN VARCHAR2,
P_UPDATE_DATE   IN VARCHAR2
);
PROCEDURE FETCH_LEVEL_DATA (    
 LEVEL_C               OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR 
);  
PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEVEL_DATA (
P_LEVEL_ID       IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
P_LEVEL_NAME     IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_NAME%TYPE,  
P_CREATED_BY     IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
P_CREATE_DATE   IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.CREATE_DATE%TYPE,
P_UPDATE_DATE   IN varchar2,
P_UPDATE_COUNT  OUT NUMBER             
);
PROCEDURE GET_LEVEL_RECORD_ID_WISE(
P_LEVEL_ID      IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
LEVEL_C         OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR 
);

PROCEDURE DELETE_LEVEL_DATA(
P_LEVEL_ID     IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
DELETE_C       OUT NUMBER
);  

END LEVEL_CRUD;
```

create package body where actual procedure is available and sql query will return count and data

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY LEVEL_CRUD AS
PROCEDURE INSERT_LEVEL_DATA (
P_LEVEL_ID      IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
P_LEVEL_NAME    IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_NAME%TYPE,
P_CREATED_BY    IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
P_CREATE_DATE   IN VARCHAR2,
P_UPDATE_DATE   IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO APP_LEVEL_MASTER
( LEVEL_ID,LEVEL_NAME,CREATED_BY,CREATE_DATE,UPDATE_DATE,STATUS)
VALUES ( ESC_LEVEL_ID.NEXTVAL,P_LEVEL_NAME,P_CREATED_BY,SYSDATE,SYSDATE,1);
END INSERT_LEVEL_DATA;


PROCEDURE FETCH_LEVEL_DATA (
LEVEL_C               OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR 
 ) AS
BEGIN
open LEVEL_C FOR 
SELECT * FROM APP_LEVEL_MASTER where STATUS = 1;
END FETCH_LEVEL_DATA;


PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEVEL_DATA (
P_LEVEL_ID       IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
P_LEVEL_NAME     IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_NAME%TYPE,  
P_CREATED_BY     IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.CREATED_BY%TYPE,
P_CREATE_DATE   IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.CREATE_DATE%TYPE,
P_UPDATE_DATE   IN varchar2,
P_UPDATE_COUNT  OUT NUMBER        
) AS
 BEGIN
  UPDATE APP_LEVEL_MASTER AUM 
 SET 
 AUM.LEVEL_NAME = P_LEVEL_NAME,
 AUM.CREATED_BY = P_CREATED_BY,
 AUM.CREATE_DATE= TO_DATE(P_CREATE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
 AUM.UPDATE_DATE=TO_DATE(sysdate) 
 WHERE AUM.LEVEL_ID = P_LEVEL_ID;
 P_UPDATE_COUNT:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;  
 END UPDATE_LEVEL_DATA;


 PROCEDURE GET_LEVEL_RECORD_ID_WISE(
  P_LEVEL_ID      IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
 LEVEL_C         OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR 

 )AS
 BEGIN    
 OPEN LEVEL_C FOR  
 SELECT * FROM APP_LEVEL_MASTER WHERE LEVEL_ID=P_LEVEL_ID;
  END GET_LEVEL_RECORD_ID_WISE;


  PROCEDURE DELETE_LEVEL_DATA(
  P_LEVEL_ID     IN APP_LEVEL_MASTER.LEVEL_ID%TYPE,
  DELETE_C       OUT NUMBER
  )AS
  BEGIN
  UPDATE  APP_LEVEL_MASTER SET STATUS='0' WHERE LEVEL_ID=P_LEVEL_ID;
  DELETE_C:=SQL%ROWcOUNT;
  END DELETE_LEVEL_DATA;  

  END LEVEL_CRUD;
```